# Tools and techniques for effective use of feature toggles in .NET

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, featuretoggle

I have read a lot about [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) but have no practical experience of using them. What tools and techniques do people recommend for effective management of feature toggles?

I imagine the simplest way would be to store toggles as true/false values in the web.config file as appSettings but this doesn't sound a particularly good method.

Ideally I would like any method of managing feature toggles to:

- Flag any uses of the toggle on removal. E.g. A compilation error
- Highlight any old toggles. I.e. A toggle that is still in place after the feature has been released

Comment: Hi Phil. You might like to try a feature toggling system I wrote called [NFeature](https://github.com/benaston/NFeature).

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion from a colleague is to store them in a .settings file. The advantage of this is that if you delete a toggle you get compiler errors anywhere the toggle has been used so you can be certain it's been completely removed from the code.

It's also possible to use some [simple techniques](http://www.philjhale.com/2012/02/simple-feature-toggles-in-net-4.html) to do feature toggling. It's not big or clever, but it's straight forward and it works.

UPDATE

Since asking this question I've had some more experience using feature toggles. I've looked at a [few of the open source tools available](http://www.philjhale.com/2012/07/a-brief-look-at-some-feature-toggle.html) and written about another [simple database driven toggling mechanism](http://www.philjhale.com/2012/07/simple-database-driven-feature-toggles.html) I've used at work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use a class with a number of boolean properties and deserialize the values from a config file.